# Redefining Quotation Marks in LaTeX

Tags: punctuation

Apparently, I have misunderstood how quotation marks have been written my entire life.  In English, the left quotation mark is a double, inverted comma on top, i.e.:

## `“`

The way I thought it was written, it turns out, is used by *literally no language on Earth*!  Specifically, a double, *mirrored* comma on top, i.e.:

## `‟`

I'd like to have LaTeX use the second form instead of the first when I use `` and ''.  How can I change LaTeX to do this?

Comment: the mapping `\` \` ` to `“` is implemented by the font, so the natural way would be to use a different font with a different `` ligature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute a token cycle to pre-scan an input and intercept occurrences of ``, replacing them in the input stream with a reflection of `''`.  Only restriction on environment is it cannot encompass catcode changing material.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}[2021-05-25]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\Characterdirective{%
  \ifx`#1\tcpeek\z
    \ifx`\z
      \tcpop\z\addcytoks{\reflectbox{''}}
    \else
      \addcytoks{#1}
    \fi
  \else
    \addcytoks{#1}
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\tokencyclexpress
Testing the ``quotes''...did I ``pass''?

This won't affect `single' use 

or even \number`x.
\endtokencyclexpress
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I could not get this to work.  I copied and pasted the TeX code you gave directly into a blank Overleaf project, and it gave me an "Undefined control sequence" on each use of the accent mark (I can't type it due to SE formatting).  It also gave a warning ("You have requested, on input line 2, version", which is verbatim the entire warning message) on the line designating to use the `tokcycle` package.  I produced a PDF with the text above, but the left quotation marks were the standard ones, not the ones shown in your image.  Your image is, however, exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @mknote Steven specified `\usepackage{tokcycle}[2021-05-25]` ie a very new version of the package, Overleaf has texlive 2020 so will not have this.  You could get the package from ctan and add it to your project.

Comment: Ah, I was not aware of that.  Uploading the .tex file from CTAN made everything work.  Porting over to my dissertation document, it seems like I'll need to add it to each chapter .tex instead of just one declaration in the main file, but that's fine. There's also an issue with a nested minipage `itemize` I have, but putting an \endtokencyclexpressbefore that list and a \tokencyclexpress after it works and throws no errors.  This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: As a side-note, this method seems to be very time-intensive on compilation, presumably because it's checking every character in the text.  It seems using `\tokencyclexpress ... \endtokencyclexpress` _only_ around blocks of text containing the quotation marks to be changed is a far better way to use this method.

Comment: It also seems that I can just use `\reflectbox{''}` to manually create the quotation mark, although my original question asked for an automated procedure.  Nevertheless, I have a good way of doing this, and hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

Comment: @mknote Actually, `tokcycle` is very efficient and fast.  Was the file/environment size you tested it on very large?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes On my test (copy and paste of your code), it worked fine. What I was speaking to was a real-world application of the scheme, namely my PhD dissertation. It's over 200 pages of mostly text. Trying to compile it on Overleaf caused a timed out error with the tokcycle enabled, but when using just `\reflectbox{''}` for the marks, it only took about 20 seconds for the entire dissertation. Note that it timed out even when I just surrounded select paragraphs of text with `\tokencyclexpress ... \endtokencyclexpress`, and when compiling individual (~20-50 page) chapters on top of that.

Comment: @mknote Well, I've never performed a token cycle on such a large document.  In such a case, it will be creating a token list the length of your document.  Perhaps this is the source of the issue.  But I'm glad you could use the `\reflectbox` directly.